# Patching commands in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3, etoolbox, patching

Is there some facility in the LaTeX3 kernel to modify existing commands like `etoolbox`'s `\preto` `\appto` and `\patchcmd` do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. The `expl3` language is useful for both programming with existing LaTeX2e code and creating new code, and so there are some facilities which are '2e-facing'. However, patching existing commands is not an area we wish to encourage: it is *much* better if interfaces are provided for altering code flows, *etc.* Patching for LaTeX2e can as you note be achieved using `etoolbox`, whilst it should not be used for `expl3` code at all (rather discussions should be undertaken to provide appropriate interfaces).

Note that `\preto` and `appto` are more-or-less the same at `\tl_put_left:Nn` and `\tl_put_right:Nn`, but there are no equivalents of `\pretocmd`/`\apptocmd`.

Comment: I tried to `\tl_put_left:Nn \existingmacro { \new \directives }` without success. Am I right to assume they only work on initialized token lists and not for arbitrary macros?

Comment: @XZS As the name says, it's adding to the left of an _existing_ token list (macro): the 'all vars must be declared' position is pretty clear in `expl3`.

Comment: @JosephWright (off-topic question): it seems `LaTeX3` parlance often refers to `token lists` which are not the same as the `token list registers or variables` from `TeX`. Am I wrong, and if not isn't it a bit confusing ?

Comment: @jfbu I guess I should have put `tl var` in the above comment: we use `tl var` to refer to a TeX macro used as a storage bin. We _don't_ use `toks (token list registers)` at all in `expl3` (well, there are a few internal places but we don't expose them). The point thus is from an `expl3` point of view there is no need to discuss `toks` at all.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for the explanation, good to know. Is this some remnant of  Lamport's `LaTeX` spirit ?

Comment: @jfbu The intention has always been that `expl3` will be 'stand-alone', _i.e._ documented fully on its own terms rather than implicitly relying on (bits of)  _The TeXbook_ as a reference. We are not there yet but that is our direction.

Comment: @JosephWright ok, thanks for answering my off-topic questions...