# Using lthooks to locally hook into command

Tags: expl3, expansion, amsthm, hooks, lthooks

Following a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695779/208544) of mine, as an exercise I'm trying to mimic the behavior of thmtools with amsthm using l3keys and lthooks. Now I am stuck on the hooks part. thmtools defines prehead, posthead, prefoot, and postfoot hooks both for each theorem environment and generically (applied to all theorems). The prehead and postfoot hooks are easy. For the posthead hook, I've figured out that the code should be added after the amsthm command `\deferred@thm@head`. (Or perhaps `\@begintheorem`? The difference is an `\ignorespaces`.)

For the generic hook, one can just do

```
\NewHook{ amsthm-keys/allthms/posthead }
\AddToHook { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/posthead } }
```

But for the local hooks, I only want to add code after `\deferred@thm@head` for that specific environment. As far as I can tell, adding to hooks is always global, so I don't see how to do this without possibly changing the definition of `\deferred@thm@head`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,kantlipsum,tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mbert/thm }
  {
    name         .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thm_name_tl,
    preheadhook  .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thm_preheadhook_tl,
    postheadhook .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl,
    prefoothook  .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thm_prefoothook_tl,
    postfoothook .tl_set:N = \l_mbert_thm_postfoothook_tl,
  }

\tl_new:N \l_mbert_thm_defaultkeys_tl
\keys_precompile:nnN { mbert/thm }
  {
    name         = \text_titlecase:n { \l_mbert_thm_envname_tl },
    preheadhook  = {},
    postheadhook = {},
    prefoothook  = {},
    postfoothook = {},
  }
  \l_mbert_thm_defaultkeys_tl

\NewHook{ amsthm-keys/allthms/prehead }
\NewHook{ amsthm-keys/allthms/posthead }
\NewHook{ amsthm-keys/allthms/prefoot }
\NewHook{ amsthm-keys/allthms/postfoot }

\AddToHook { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/posthead } }
% How to hook into \deferred@thm@head locally?

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mbert_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_mbert_thm_defaultkeys_tl
    \keys_set:nn { mbert/thm } { #2 }
    \exp_args:NnV \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } \l_mbert_thm_preheadhook_tl % local prehead hook
    \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/prehead } } % generic prehead hook
    \AddToHook { env/#1/end } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/postfoot } } % generic postfoot hook
    \exp_args:NnV \AddToHook { env/#1/end } \l_mbert_thm_postfoothook_tl % local postfoot hook
    \mbert_thm_new:ne { #1 } { \l_mbert_thm_name_tl }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \mbert_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mbert_thm_new:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}[
    preheadhook=\begin{tcolorbox},
    postfoothook=\end{tcolorbox}
    ]
\NewThm{cor}[
    name=Corollary,
    postheadhook=ABC
    ]
\NewThm{lemma}

\AddToHook{amsthm-keys/allthms/posthead}{***}
\AddToHook{amsthm-keys/allthms/postfoot}{END THEOREM}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[2][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{cor}
\kant[2][1]
\end{cor}

\begin{lemma}
\kant[2][1]
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I obviously can't add something like

```
\exp_args:NnV \AddToHook { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl
```

to the definition of `\NewThm` as then each declaration of `postheadhook=` would add code to `\deferred@thm@head`.

Essentially I want the effect of

```
\AddToHook{env/theorem/begin}{\apptocmd{\deferred@thm@head}{CODE}{}{}}
```

but using the kernel hooks. From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266898/208544), I know there's no direct way to get the behavior of `\apptocmd`. Is there general advice for locally hooking into commands from other packages like this?

---

### Additional attempt

With @cfr's help in the comments, the idea of nesting `\AddToHookNext{cmd/deferred@thm@head/after}` inside `\AddToHook{env/<envname>/begin}` seems promising. Indeed, adding e.g.

```
\AddToHook { env/cor/begin } { \AddToHookNext { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } {HHH} }
```

has the desired effect. However, when I try to make this automatic in the definition of `\NewThm`, nothing happens when `postheadhook` is given a value:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mbert_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_mbert_thm_defaultkeys_tl
    \keys_set:nn { mbert/thm } { #2 }
    \exp_args:NnV \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } \l_mbert_thm_preheadhook_tl % local prehead hook
    \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/prehead } } % generic prehead hook
%%% This next line is new.
    \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } { \exp_args:NnV \AddToHookNext { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl }
    \AddToHook { env/#1/end } { \UseHook { amsthm-keys/allthms/postfoot } } % generic postfoot hook
    \exp_args:NnV \AddToHook { env/#1/end } \l_mbert_thm_postfoothook_tl % local postfoot hook
    \mbert_thm_new:ne { #1 } { \l_mbert_thm_name_tl }
  }
```

Is it perhaps an expansion issue?

#### Yet another attempt

I don't understand why, but my above attempt seems to work if I prefix the added line with `\exp_args:Nnf`, as in

```
\exp_args:Nnf \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } { \exp_args:NnV \AddToHookNext { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl }
```

o-type expansion does nothing, and e-type expansion produces an error if `postheadhook` contains something other than pure text. Just lucky, or is this how to use f-type expansion?

Comment: @cfr Doesn't that only execute the code once? It needs to be executed every time the theorem is called

Comment: Yes and sorry for deleting it before your comment showed up. It does prove adding to hooks isn't always global, I suppose.

Comment: @cfr No problem. It does give me an idea, though. Maybe `\AddToHook{env/#1/before}{\AddToHookNext{cmd/deferred@thm@head/after}{\l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl}}` (with expansion adjusted as necessary)

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that. There's an example on page 6 of the documentation of nesting hooks. So if you can hook into the correct environment anywhere, it seems you should be able to add the code to only the next hook every time. However, my experiments with the new hooks to date have not been terribly successful ....

Comment: Can you add to the hooks for the specific environment you create? E.g. `lemma` or whatever?

Comment: @cfr See my additional attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for the local hooks, I only want to add code after
> `\deferred@thm@head` for that specific environment. As far as I can
> tell, adding to hooks is always global, so I don't see how to do this
> without possibly changing the definition of `\deferred@thm@head`
>
> […]
>
> Essentially I want the effect of
>
> ```tex
> \AddToHook{env/theorem/begin}{\apptocmd{\deferred@thm@head}{CODE}{}{}}
> ```
>
> but using the kernel hooks.

Here are 5 different options:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter \ExplSyntaxOn
    \def\pretext#1{before <#1>}
    \def\posttext#1{after <#1>}

    \NewDocumentEnvironment
        { one }
        { }
        { \pretext{one} }
        { \posttext{one} }

    \NewDocumentEnvironment
        { two }
        { }
        { \pretext{two} }
        { \posttext{two} }


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Option 1 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Use \globaldefs to trick \hook_gput_code into actually behaving like a
    %% hypothetical \hook_put_code. This is a complete hack and wildly
    %% unsupported, so PLEASE DON'T ACTUALLY DO THIS.
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { env / two / begin } { . } {
    %     \PackageWarning{BAD~ IDEA!}{PLEASE~ DON'T~ ACTUALLY~ DO~ THIS!}
    %     \int_set:Nn \globaldefs { -1 }
    %     \hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd / pretext / after } { . } { \textbf { NEW } }
    %     \int_set:Nn \globaldefs { 0 }
    % }
    %%% End Option 1


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Option 2 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Add the patch using a "cmd/..." hook at the beginning of the
    %% environment, and remove it at the end.
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { env / two / begin } { . } {
    %     \hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd / pretext / after } { . } { \textbf { NEW } }
    % }
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { env / two / end } { . } {
    %     \hook_gremove_code:nn { cmd / pretext / after } { . }
    % }
    %%% End Option 2


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Option 3 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Add a one-time "cmd/..." hook at the beginning of the environment.
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { env / two / begin } { . } {
    %     \hook_gput_next_code:nn { cmd / pretext / after } { \textbf { NEW } }
    % }
    %%% End Option 3


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Option 4 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Locally patch the command by directly using expl3 commands.
    %
    % \cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Npn { NpV }
    %
    % \cctab_const:Nn \c_package_cctab {
    %     \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab
    %     \char_set_catcode_letter:N @
    % }
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { env / two / begin } { . } {
    %     \tl_set_rescan:Nnx
    %         \l_tmpa_tl
    %         { \cctab_select:N \c_package_cctab }
    %         { \cs_replacement_spec:N \pretext }
    %
    %     \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textbf { NEW } }
    %     \cs_set:NpV \pretext #1 { \l_tmpa_tl }
    % }
    %%% End Option 4


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Option 5 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Globally patch the command, but make the patch value depend on the current
    %% environment.
    %
    % \prop_new:N \g__example_aftertext_prop
    %
    % \hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd / pretext / after } { . } {
    %     \prop_item:NV \g__example_aftertext_prop \@currenvir
    % }
    %
    % \prop_gput:Nnn \g__example_aftertext_prop { two } { \textbf { NEW } }
    %%% End Option 5
\ExplSyntaxOff \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{one}
        \emph{body}
    \end{one}

    \begin{two}
        \emph{body}
    \end{two}

    \begin{one}
        \emph{body}
    \end{one}

    \begin{two}
        \emph{body}
    \end{two}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

> I don't understand why, but my above attempt seems to work if I prefix
> the added line with `\exp_args:Nnf`, as in
>
> ```tex
> \exp_args:Nnf \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } { \exp_args:NnV \AddToHookNext { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after } \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl }
> ```
>
> o-type expansion does nothing, and e-type expansion produces an error
> if `postheadhook` contains something other than pure text. Just lucky,
> or is this how to use f-type expansion?

`e`-type expansion will fail if `postheadhook` contains anything fragile. `o`-type expansion doesn't work because it expands exactly once, and `\exp_args:NnV` takes way more expansions than that to work.

`f`-type expansion is inappropriate 99% of the time, but it seems fine here. I'd *slightly* prefer

```tex
\exp_args:Nnf \AddToHook { env/#1/begin } {
    %          v   vvvvvvvvvvvv
    \exp_args:NNnV \exp_stop_f: \AddToHookNext { cmd/deferred@thm@head/after }
    \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl
}
```

just in case `\AddToHookNext` were to blow up when expanded, but it (and most other LaTeX commands) are protected, so this doesn't really make a difference in this case.

(What would be best would be something like `\hook_gput_code:nne … \hook_gput_next_code:ne … \exp_not:V \l_mbert_thm_postheadhook_tl`, but that throws an error for some unknown reason.)

Comment: This is marvelous, thank you. For option 2, it's relevant to my use-case that your code removes everything from the hook. If you add a label it only removes the code just added

Comment: Do you have a preference for one of these options? Option 3, which is what I came to in my "Yet another...", seems most natural to me, but there could be deficiencies I'm not thinking of

Comment: In my first comment, by "everything" I mean everything added in the current package/file. Code added in other packages should not be affected, I think

Comment: @mbert I'd slightly prefer option 5 since the command hooks can be slightly fragile, so it's better to only patch the command once. It's also nice since you defer setting the patch content until you use it, so you can just save things in `\g__example_aftertext_prop` without worrying too much about expansion. Options 3 and 4 are both pretty good too, so if those work better for your use case, then I see no issues with that.